# C dynamic loaded library

Tags: c

I have such a code

```
    #include <dlfcn.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "timer.h"

    #define SIZE 9000

    void *memorylib;
    void *arraylib;

    typedef struct {
        int rows;
        int columns;
        long **d;
    } array;



    int main(){

        memorylib = dlopen("libmemory.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        if(!memorylib){
            exit(-1);
        }
        arraylib = dlopen("libarray.so",RTLD_LAZY);
        if(!arraylib) {
            exit(-1);
        }

        typedef void (*memory_initialize)(long);

        typedef void * (*memory_add)(long);
        typedef array *(*memory_allocate)(int,int);


        memory_add add = (memory_add) dlsym(memorylib,"add");
        memory_initialize initialize = (memory_initialize) dlsym(memorylib, "initialize");
        memory_allocate allocate = (memory_allocate) dlsym(arraylib,"allocate");



        initialize(SIZE*sizeof(int)/1024 + 1);

        int rows = 10;
        int columns = 10;
        array *m = allocate(rows,columns);

    dlclose(memorylib);
    dlclose(arraylib);
        return 0;
    }
```

and initialize method works, but when I try to use allocate method I get an error 
symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libarray.so: undefined symbol: add

I use this add method in my allocate method which comes from memory.h

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>

     #include "array.h"
     #include "memory.h"


    array * allocate(int rows, int columns) {
// printf("%i",sizeof(array));
array *m = (array *) add(sizeof(array));
    m->rows = rows;
    m->columns = columns;
int i;
    long **d = (long**)add(rows* sizeof(long*));
    for(i=0;i< rows;i++) {
        d[i] = (long *) add(columns * sizeof(long));
    }
    m->d = d;

return m;
```

}

How to fix it ? It's probably fail, because I don't load library dynamically to file containing allocate method ?

Comment: make memory_add (and the others) global or pass them to the function.

Comment: I made it global, but it still not work. Is there other possible way instead of passing them to the function, because I have to change a lot of code in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the flag `RTLD_GLOBAL` when loading `libmemory.so` so that symbols in it will be available for use by subsequently loaded libraries (such as `libarray.so`).  By default, symbols in a library are only visible to that library and to `dlsym` calls using that library.

Comment: I changed it to RTLD_GLOBAL but then I entered this if statement    if(!memorylib) and exit

Comment: @Yeynno: You can't change it just to RTLD_GLOBAL.  Per the dlopen() manual page, RTLD_NOW or RTLD_LAZY must be set.  As the flags argument is a bitmask, try `dlopen("libmemory.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL)`.

Comment: @Yeynno: You might want to try adding calls to `dlerror` to get error messages...